# FFT y-scale confusion - Python scipy

Tags: python, scipy, fft, binary-data

I am performing FFTs on random binary data. I am confused by what the y-axis scaling factor is. My random data has a repetition rate of 400Hz, or a interval between measurements of 0.0025 seconds. The number of data points is 12489.

The code below works, and gives a mean amplitude of around 50.

**My questions:**

- What does y.size exactly do in this context?
- What is the expected amplitude of an FFT performed on 12489 random binary points? (I understand that this question is specifically for here, but if it's understood I'd appreciate the help).

The working code: (If you wish to copy and paste it into Python to look at)

```
from numpy import *
import pylab as P
import numpy as N
import scipy as S
import array
import scipy.fftpack
from random import *

#Produce random binary data
x = N.linspace(0,12489,12489)
randBinList = lambda n: [randint(0,1) for b in range(1,n+1)]
y = randBinList(12489)
y = asarray(y)

#Perform an FFT
FFT = abs(S.fft(y)) 
freqs = S.fftpack.fftfreq(y.size,0.0025) 

#What does y.size do???

x_range = freqs[(freqs>0)]
y_range = FFT[(freqs>0)]

P.plot(x_range,y_range,'.r')
P.show()
```

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

`fftfreq` generates the frequencies of each bin of the result of the FFT, which is computed from the number of samples you pass in and the sampling rate ([doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html)).